# PHP: adding timestamp to filename vs adding it inside the file

Tags: php, caching, timestamp

I'm creating a cache system for myself using .txt files and the cache time is different for different things so which would be better:

(I use "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6" as test md5 hash)

a) Adding the expiration time to the filename in seconds like "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6-180.txt" (cache limited to 180 seconds).

b) Adding the expiration time to the first row of the file and adding the cached stuff from 2nd row onwards. Naming the file just "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6.txt".

With a) I have to scan the whole dir and explode all file names with "-" and check if explode[0] equals with the hash.

With b) I can just use file_exists() and then read the first row to see if the cache is still valid.

Which should I use or is there a c) way?

EDIT: I don't know if it was clear or not but I'm trying to find the best way performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's a third way - even a fourth - using a some DB handling and `unlink()`.

For example:

When you make your new cache file, put the filename in a table, and an expiration date. Then when you execute your script see if the expiration date is now, if so unlink the file.

The fourth way is not efficient at all, but works.

```
foreach(glob('files/*') as $file)
{
  if(filemtime($file) < strtotime('-180 seconds'))
  {
    unlink($file);
  }
}
```

I would go with your first option, but with a better format... expirationDate_crc32hash.file. For example: 180_127264de.txt

Then it'd be easier to explode at _, use `strstr`, or `substr`

Comment: I'm going to cache mysql results so I don't want to use anything DB related to find the cached data.

The cache folder can end up having up to 1000 different .txt files. Globbing through them is more efficient than checking file_exists on particular hash and just reading first row of the file for the expiration time?

Comment: Don't know about that, but my guess is it's not as fast, but PHP is hard to predict.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to create folders (which would be the unique ids?) then inside you would create a file named as the expiration date? I think this allows for maximum flexibility, sorting of expiration dates inside the folder and you reserve the inside of the file for actual content.